# How to move a SwiftUI View by dragging one of its subview (child)?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var location: CGPoint = CGPoint(x: 150, y: 100)
    @GestureState private var startLocation: CGPoint? = nil
    @State var windowSize = CGSize(width: 300, height: 200)
    
    var dragGesture: some Gesture {
        DragGesture().onChanged { value in
            location = (startLocation ?? location) + value.translation
        }.updating($startLocation) {
            (_, startLocation, _) in
                startLocation = startLocation ?? location
        }
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            //Title
            ZStack {
                Color.green
                Text("Title bar")
            }.frame(height: 30)
            .gesture(dragGesture) // (1)
            
            //Contents
            Spacer()
            Text("contents")
            Spacer()
        }.background(Color.gray)
            .frame(width: windowSize.width, height: windowSize.height)
            .position(location) // (3)
            //.gesture(dragGesture) // (2)
    }
}

func +(lhs: CGPoint, rhs: CGSize) -> CGPoint {
    return CGPoint(
        x: lhs.x + rhs.width,
        y: lhs.y + rhs.height
    )
}
```

The dragging effect works if (1) is commented out and (2) uncommented. But I want to recognize drag gestures **only on the title bar** to move the whole *View*. What I tried is to add a gesture to the *ZStack* (1) modifying the state of the *VStack* (3).

Answer (score 0):

I got a solution later.

```
ZStack {
    TitleBar() //some view
        .position(/*position for title bar*/)
        .gesture(dragGesture)

    Contents() //some view
        .position(/*position for contents below, which can be a computed variable from TitleBar's (state) position*/)
}
```

Comment: It doesn't matter if you add modifiers to the ZStack like shadows or masks.